# Handling different user types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm designing an application that has two [three including administrators] user types: Buyers and Sellers. When a user signs up, it's assumed that they're signing up to simply purchase something [a Buyer account]. However, if they wish to become a Seller, there should be an option for them to post their items for sale, [become a Seller]. This becomes important, as users can switch back and forth between account types.

Of course, a Seller can buy items as well.

### The problem

The problem I'm facing is that Sellers have `profile` pages where buyers can go to view their items for sale, whereas Buyers do not. However, both user types have a `My Account` page that they can use to update their information.

### Possible design choices

#### Single table inheritence

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Seller < User
  has_many :sale_items
end

class Buyer < User
  # nothing here.. I guess this is the "default" user type
end
```

I thought about this approach because then I could clearly separate the user types. For example, the show page for each user is clearly separated. However, this could lead to repeated code in each controller, and introduce a problem when switching between user types.

---

#### Just use declarative_authorization or CanCan to add functionality to the base user type

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :sale_items  # only for Sellers
                        # if the user is a seller, allow them to add sale_items
end
```

I thought of this approach because a Seller is basically a Buyer with additional functionality, such as posting items for sale. This could lead to a lot of view logic, though. For example `if @user.role == "seller" render _some_seller_partial`. I also don't like the idea of checking for a hard coded string in the view. Well, I guess I could do `if @user.seller?`

#### Other design choices?

I'm really interested in hearing how other people would model this application. I've been thinking about this for a couple days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the second option, but with declarative_authorization instead of cancan, and I'd use the role_model Gem to store the role in the user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :sale_items  # only for Sellers
                        # if the user is a seller, allow them to add sale_items

  #  t.integer :roles_mask , :default => 0    # for role_model
end
```

declarative_authorization is a bit more powerful than CanCan, and I found it to scale better once a project needs more / more complex roles..

If you store your roles using the role_model Gem, it stores them as a bitmap in the roles_mask attribute.
This means that a user can have many roles, e.g. can be a Seller and a Buyer at the same time, and an Admin or Moderator if you like.

See:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

And:

http://everydayrails.com/2011/10/06/rails-authorization.html

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend handling Seller "profiles?" I would like to keep things as DRY as possible. I was thinking about using Users#show for a "My Account" type of page, and also a Seller profile view page. declarative_authorization or CanCan would take care of whether a user could edit his/her account. However, the problem with this is that people could view a Buyers account by hard coding an ID into the URL.

Comment: I'd do it with a has_one relationship -- that is actually a has-on-or-zero relationship!  So you can create a profile if it's a Seller, and for a Buyer you can just leave it nil. When you display a user's Profile, you should just make an if-statement that it's not showing it if the roles don't include Seller, or the profile is nil

Comment: Well, a Buyer should have the ability to update their account settings (ie, email, password, etc..) Are you recommending this be in Users#show, while the Seller profile page be in Profiles#show?

Comment: it's probably best to have a profile for both of them, but in the View you might have some additional fields for the Sellers (the model contains all the attributes, but for Buyers some are nil)

Comment: I agree, but this brings me back to my original comment that the public should be restricted to viewing _only_ Seller profiles. Buyer profiles are more of a way for a user to manage his/her own profile.

Comment: well, in the View, you can do something like if current_user.has_role(:seller) { display the profile }

Comment: That would limit the users who are allowed to view any profile to Sellers. I'm trying to limit the publicly accessible profiles to Sellers, while Buyers can still view their own. I think the only way to do this is to make User#show specific to the current user, and Profile#view publicly accessible but limited to Sellers via User.find(:id).is_seller?

Answer (score 1):

I would pick the cancan option. Is a wonderful gem, well documented, easy to use, actively mantained, and you have lots of tutorials (since it a gem created by Ryan Bates, from Railscasts, you can be sure that you have an episode for it)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the cancan option, and use the `draper` gem for the view logic. There are Railscasts for both gems.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper